# How do I find the value of $\operatorname{LCM} (a_1^k,a_2^k, \ldots ,a_n^k) \pmod {m}$?

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation, gcd-and-lcm

LCM can be upto or greater than $10^{50}$.
$k$ and $m$ are upto $10^9$.

My current approach is

1. Finding the LCM .
2. (LCM % m)^k=A.
3. A % m.

This is working but takes a long time in finding LCM using GCD.
Is there any other way?

Comment: So what exactly is the question here?

Comment: Given three integers N,M,K and array of integers a1,a2,...,an.
Find the value of LCM(a1^k,a2^k,...,an^k) mod M,

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the information in your comment.  Also please use MathJax to format your post.  The question should be in the body of the post as well as its title.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  Programming competitions generally ask that large numbers be expressed $\pmod {(10^9+7)}$ or the like.

Comment: Yes it's from some competition.

Comment: @BhaveshWadhwani What competition is it from?

Comment: Are $m$ and $M$ supposed to be the same number?

Comment: You're saying that finding LCM is taking a long time using GCD. How are you calculating that exactly?

Comment: I find it by starting with ans = a1 then in a loop I for i=2 to i=n .calculate ans= ai * ans/ GCD(ai, ans)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** there is no need to actually calculate $LCM(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$. We only have to find $LCM \bmod m$. Instead calculate $d=GCD(a_1,\ldots,a_n,m)$.

Let $x = LCM(a_1,\ldots,a_n) \bmod m$. This means that $x = LCM - \ell m$ for some integer $\ell$.
The right hand side is divisible by $d$, therefore $x$ is divisible by $d$ as well.
So we have $x = d\cdot(\frac{LCM}d - \ell \frac md)$ and we can write: $$x=d\cdot\left(\frac{LCM}{d} \bmod \frac md\right) = d\cdot\left(LCM(\frac{a_1}d,\ldots,\frac{a_n}d)\bmod \frac md\right).$$